# How to add View below other view in ViewController in iOS?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, uiscrollview

In my app i am creating view controller with mixed of `UILabel` and `UITextview` which want to be scrollable because the text are dynamic and also exceeds vertical screen size.

I am currently having Scrollview which has subviews as below. Views are created in **Xcode 4.3 Storyboard**.

**UILabel1(Say Heading)**

**UITextView1(Dynamic text which can be any size)**

**UILabel2(Second Heading)**

**UITextView2(Dynamic text which can be any size)**

and so on.

The problem is

When the `UITextView1` has more content then it overlaps with `UILabel2` which i don't want.

I would like to have `UILabel1` on top of scrollView and `UITextView1` below the `UILabel1`. `UILabel2` below `UITextView1`  and so on.

What i have to do to achieve this?

EDIT

In Storyboard

![enter image description here][1]

In Simulator

![enter image description here][2]

Thanks for your help guys. Much appreciated.

Code

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view.

[scrollView setScrollEnabled:YES];     
[self.view addSubview:cockTailNameLabel];
[self.view insertSubview:txtIngredients belowSubview:cockTailNameLabel];
[self.view insertSubview:scrollView belowSubview:cockTailNameLabel];
//[scrollView]

[self.cockTailNameLabel setText:self.passcockTailName];  

[_txtUse setText:self.passUse]; 
[_txtUse setEditable:NO];
[_txtUse setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];

CGRect useFrame = _txtUse.frame;
useFrame.size.height = _txtUse.contentSize.height;
_txtUse.frame = useFrame; 

[txtIngredients setText:self.passIngredients];
[txtIngredients setEditable:NO];
[txtIngredients setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];
CGRect ingredientFrame = txtIngredients.frame;
ingredientFrame.size.height = txtIngredients.contentSize.height;
txtIngredients.frame = ingredientFrame;  


[txtRecipe setText:self.passReceipe];
[txtRecipe setEditable:NO];
[txtRecipe setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];
CGRect recipeFrame = txtIngredients.frame;
recipeFrame.size.height = txtRecipe.contentSize.height;
txtRecipe.frame = recipeFrame;

[scrollView insertSubview:_txtUse belowSubview:cockTailNameLabel];
[scrollView insertSubview:titleIngredients belowSubview:_txtUse];
[scrollView insertSubview:txtIngredients belowSubview:titleIngredients];
[scrollView insertSubview:btnReceipe belowSubview:txtIngredients];
[scrollView insertSubview:btnHome belowSubview:txtIngredients];
[scrollView insertSubview:txtRecipe belowSubview:btnHome];
[scrollView insertSubview:btnfacebookShare belowSubview:txtRecipe];
[scrollView insertSubview:btnTwitterShare belowSubview:txtRecipe];



/*[scrollView addSubview:_txtUse];
[scrollView addSubview:titleIngredients];
[scrollView addSubview:txtIngredients];
[scrollView addSubview:btnReceipe];
[scrollView addSubview:btnHome];
[scrollView addSubview:txtRecipe];
[scrollView addSubview:btnfacebookShare];
[scrollView addSubview:btnTwitterShare];*/

[scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, 1000)];

NSLog(@"RecipeName :%@ ",passcockTailName);
```

}

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In Storyboard or IB you can rearrange them freely.

In code you do `- (void)insertSubview:(UIView *)view belowSubview:(UIView *)siblingSubview`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I want to add those views in `UIScrollView` how to achieve that.. will this work

Comment: Are all the views in your Storyboard? There's an arrow button at the lower left corner of the Storyboard, and when you expand it you can see your UI elements in a list. Within your scrollview, the lower you get in that list the higher the element is positioned. So you just reorder them the way you like.

Comment: Yes all the views are in storyboard. I coudln't test it now because i dont have mac on home now i will test it tomorrow and let your know thanks for your support.+1

Comment: hmm... that's weird. can you upload a screenshot of your Storyboard if you still want to try?

Comment: ohohoh.... by below do you mean under, i.e. when you have lots of text other stuff get pushed down? I thought you are talking about layering.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15080/discussion-between-vinoth-and-iblue)

Comment: Hi iBlue.. If you could please look at [mypost](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11885673/how-to-pass-data-back-from-one-view-to-other-view-in-ios) please.. I am facing problem in sending data back from one view to other view. Thanks

Comment: @iBlue..i have small problem in displaying contents.. As we discussed on that day its working perfectly fine.. I am using delegate in that View. So when i click one button it goes to other view.. then it will come back to the view with the dynamic details.. The problem is here the CGRect frame get increasing on the size.. Have you got any idea pls.. Much appreciated

Comment: I think you are using += ? When you go back the view is already loaded so your changes to the frames are already effective. I bet the code that executes the increment got executed again. Remember the other day I told you to be careful about +=?

Comment: Woo.. Yeah thanks for your reply man.. yes i think that will be the problem.. In that case what i have to use for += sum Blue.. Sorry to ask you again

Comment: either call the method in `viewDidLoad` in case the content doesn't change, or avoid += (just set the value directly, like `a.frame.size.width = 500` or something), or first set the height back to default and then use +=.

Comment: I am using delegate so i think i can't use that method in ViewDidLoad. Is it possible to call ViewDidLoad from delegate.. height back to default in the sense to 0.

Comment: i'm not sure what you meant, but just one of two options: either have your code that adjust height only execute when the view is first loaded, or have your code change the height only when it hasn't been changed. You can definitely first set the height to 0 and then do +=.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15280/discussion-between-vinoth-and-iblue)

Answer (score 1):

In code (in viewDidLoad):

```
UIScrollView *scroll =[[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGrectMake(0,0 320, 480)];
[self.view addSubview:scroll];
// code to init your UI object
UILabel *uilabel1 = [[UIlabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGrectMake(10,10, 100, 40)]; // example 
uilabel1.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:10];
uilabel1.text = @"UILabel1";
uilabel1.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
//
//
UILabel *uilabel2 = [[UIlabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGrectMake(10, 10 + 10 + uilabel1.frame.origin.y, 100, 40)]; // example
uilabel2.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:10];
uilabel2.text = @"UILabel2";
uilabel2.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
//
//
[scroll addSubview:uilabel1];
[uilabel1 releale];
[scroll addSubview:uilabel2];
[uilabel2 releale];
//
//
// in end 
float offset = 10.0 * 2; // offset between uiobjects, N - number of objects
scroll.contentSize = CGSizeMake (0, 0, uilabel1.frame.size.height + uilabel2.frame.size.height + offset, 320);
```

Note that you may set frame (and other properties) of yours uiobjects and adds it in order to descend.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.. what properties i need to set..+1

Comment: it's my pleasure.. i wrote not correct - not properties, rather preferences..  may be it be shadow for label text... or label text (for uilabel), text color, text alignment etc. (Whatever you can set for IB also you can through code)

Comment: you use xib (storyboard) and code both? Better if you use this things separately. Did you set frame for all views? Did you set scroll.contentSize correctly? don't forget adding to next object's frame size of previous view + offset like in edit code above

Comment: yes i am using both xib an code.. may be thats the problem.. updated my question with code please check it

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15072/discussion-between-vinoth-and-frankwhite)

Answer (score 0):

You can tell next view to start from the end of the first view like so:

```
startYOfNextView = firstView.frame.origin.y position + firstView.frame.size.height;
```

Do the same for the rest of the other view. If your view has variable text length, you may need to precaculate the height of the string based on a specific font e.g.:

```
CGSize maxSize = CGSizeMake(widthOfView, 9999999);
CGSize expectedSize = CGSizeMake(stringVar sizeWithFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial"] withMaxSize:maxSize lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap);
```

then tell your dynamic view to use the height of expectedSize variable like so:

```
myDynamicView = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(..., expectedSize.height)];
```

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is labels are coming on top of the textview (Overlapped), right?

In This case, you are modifying the height of the textview dynamically. If its just for display purpose you can set the text to a UILabel with numberOfLines = 0 instead of UITextview; As its added to scrollview adding a label will be fine.

Also you need to modify the origin.y of the remaining views so that it will be properly aligned. ie, secondView.origin.y = firstView.origin.y + firstView.size.height + offset. Likewise modify the origin of the remaining views wrt the just above view. So that its origin will lie outside the previous view frame.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had to project it over the parent view, so remember there is also something,

```
- (void)insertSubview:(UIView *)view aboveSubview:(UIView *)siblingSubview
```

Answer (score 0):

I think adding a transparent UI button is the fastest solution. You could add it once and then show / hide whenever you need to disable all views below the current one (assuming the "current" view, say a popup, was added last to your superview).

Declare an instance variable `UIButton* _parentDisablingOverlay;` in your popup view, then add this in its `init` or `layoutSubviews` method:

```
_parentDisablingOverlay = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0, self.superview.frame.size.width, self.superview.frame.size.height)];
[self.superview insertSubview:_parentDisablingOverlay belowSubview:self];
_parentDisablingOverlay.hidden = true;
```

Later on, when you want to show the popup and disable everything below:

```
- (void) open {
   self.hidden = false;
   _parentDisablingOverlay.hidden = false;
}
```

Similarly to close and re-enable everything:

```
- (void) close {
    self.hidden = true;
    _parentDisablingOverlay.hidden = true;
}
```