# How to pass data back from one view to other View in IOS?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, uiviewcontroller, modalviewcontroller

I am able to pass data from one view to other view without any problem. But here is my situation i am facing problem.

Let's say
        **->   Passing data to other view**

```
ViewA->ViewB This working perfectly fine 
ViewB->ViewC This working perfectly fine
ViewC->ViewB Here is the problem.
```

I tried using **push segue** ,it goes to ViewB but when i press back button it goes to **ViewC->back button->ViewB->back button->View A. From ViewB when i press back button it must goes to ViewA.**

Tried using **modal segue**, it goes to ViewB but then i can't go any where.

**As i am new to iOs I am really haven't got any idea about how to achieve this?**

**How to pass data back to ViewB from ViewC?**

I think you guys can help me.

**Edit**

In View A i am calling ViewB like this

```
-(void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"RemixScreen"])
{

    if([self.recipeFrom isEqualToString:@"ViewB"])
    {

        ViewB *reciepe = [segue destinationViewController];
        //somedata i will pass here

    }  
}
 }
```

In View B i am calling like this

```
-(void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
  {
if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"ViewA"])
{  
    ViewA *data = [segue destinationViewController];
    //some data  
}
}
```

Thanks for your help guys.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The correct way to do this is to use delegates.  You use properties in prepareForSegue to pass data forward and delegates to pass data back.

The way it works is to have a delegate property in ViewC that is set by ViewB in prepareForSegue.  That way ViewC can communicate with ViewB via a protocol you set up.

EDIT: Adding code to demonstrate:

ViewControllerBInterface:

```
@protocol ViewBProtocol

- (void)setData:(NSData *)data;

@end

@interface ViewBController: UIViewController <ViewBProtocol>
...
@end
```

Here we make ViewBController follow our protocol that ViewCController will communicate to.

Next up is ViewCController interface:

```
@interface ViewCController: UIViewController

@property (nonatomic, weak) id<ViewBProtocol> delegate;

...

@end
```

Now we look at ViewBController's prepareForSegue:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    UIViewController* controller = [segue destinationViewController];
    if ([controller isKindOfClass:[ViewCController class]])
    {
        ViewCController* viewCController = (ViewCController *)controller;
        viewCController.delegate = self;
    }
}
```

As you can see we link the ViewC controller to the ViewB one via the delegate property.  Now we do something in ViewC:

```
- (void)sendData:(NSData *)data
{
    [self.delegate setData:data];
}
```

And you can use that in your viewWillDisappear method of ViewCController if you wanted to.

Comment: I tried delegates now but its ViewC doesn't called ViewB i am not sure what happening.. Do you have any nice tutorial to communicate with protocol

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer when i tried to set property for delegate i end up in error  `@synthesize of 'weak' property is only allowed in ARC or GC mode` googled it but couldn't find the exact solution..

Comment: Not using ARC? :)  Yeah, strong and weak are ARC only, use retain instead.

Comment: @Abizern what is more correct about using delegates for passing back data, than using the parent view as the model? Also in a view hierarchy with more than 2 or 3 views the code starts to become more illegible as you end up with lots of unnessary delegates.

Comment: It breaks the MVC paradigm for one, plus using protocols decouples the view controllers somewhat.  What if ViewC isn't coming from ViewB but from ViewB2?

Comment: @jonathanlking Just to add - watch any of the WWDC videos on using Storyboards - the `prepareForSegue…` method is to push data up the stack and delegation is the preferred way to pass data down the stack.

Comment: Ok, but what if you want to be able to jump from ViewC to ViewA (or from any view to any view) using delegates you would have to implement the protocol in n(n+1)/2 view controllers. Wheras using my solution you wouldn't have to write any extra code. I'm not saying my way is better, just that they both have their merits.

Comment: (Although you'll probably tell me that's not how a stack of view controllers should work). ;)

Comment: I see nothing wrong in implementing the protocol since information for ViewA should be handled in ViewA

Comment: To improve it's MVC correctness, how about if the parent view has a strong pointer to a model which then holds all the data collected from child views? The child views then just accesss the model, through the parent.

Comment: Without other information, I would say that the parent view should not have a strong pointer to the model.  That's the job of the view controller.

Comment: When you jump from ViewC to ViewA, it will still work as ViewC controller will dealloc (sending data to the delegate of ViewB), then ViewB will dealloc (sending data to the delegate of ViewA).

Answer (score 2):

The way I have gotten around this problem in a recent project is the following;

**View A** is the `parentViewController`, so can be accessed from **View B** and **View C** at any time like this;

```
ViewAClass *parentView = (ViewAClass *)self.parentViewController;
```

You can then read and write to a property of the **View A**, like;

```
NSString *string = parentView.someStringProperty;
```

or

```
parentView.someStringProperty = @"Hello World";
```

EDIT - "To go back from view B to ViewA with out back button"

```
[parentView popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer budddy.. How will you go back from view B to ViewA with out back button

Comment: Witin ViewB call: `[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];`

Comment: @jonathanlking edited my question please check it..where i want to declare the `ViewAClass *parentView = (ViewAClass *)self.parentViewController;` i am really confused sorry this may simple

Comment: Ok, what's happening is called casting. You know what class viewA is, but the compiler doesn't, so by putting `(ViewAClass *)` before `self.parentViewController` you are letting the compiler know what class it is. In your code instead of "ViewAClass" write the name of the class viewA's controller is.

Comment: As Chutu said.. I got solved my issue thanks for your support.. +1 for you

Answer (score -1):

Are you using navigation controller? If yes, you can easily pass data with Singleton, which is my favorite way to do that and also its easy to use. Otherwise, if you're trying to navigate through views with buttons or something, try to set a identifier to your segue, then call the method "performSegueWithIdentifier"

Comment: In my project i want to send data back when shaking is finished.. i tried performsegueWithidentifier but end up in the problem which asked in the question

Comment: If you use a singleton to pass data around you are just coupling your view controllers to a the singleton.