# Passing parameter when pop view

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I am building an ios app where there's navigation between two views `A` and `B`.

The navigation pattern is:

```
ViewController A >>> PushViewController >>> ViewController B

ViewController A <<< PopViewController <<< ViewController B
```

I want that when `B` pops back to `A`, A updates some UI element accordingly. For example, `A` view controller displays some label with text, in `B` user modifies the text, and when view pops back, I want `A` to update and reflect the change.

The question is: How `A` can know when it is poped from `B`? and how `A` can get data passed by `B` so it can update the content? What is a good practice to tackle this kind of issue?

Thank you

Comment: Did you think of implementing a delegate protocol for your controllers?

Comment: You can use nsnotification center or embed your main view controller on a navegation controller and set a segue using storyboard and dispatch it using prepareForSegue and pass the values using push

Comment: Reading again your question you need a navegation controller. And to pass values from a to b you need to push the values you think b expects for that you import your view controller.h b on a view controller.m and must know that the values you pass to b must be defined on a. Later using storyboard link a and b with a push segue. Tell me if it helps

Comment: Delegation is by far the simplest and least bug prone approach you can take. I would stay away from notifications in a simple one to one relationship.

Comment: I think just using the property reference, and UIViewController life-cycle methods will solve the problem, just create a property in both the controller, pass from `A->B`, on `B` assign the value and POP, A will have the value since it had same reference. update the values in A on `viewWillAppear`, or, `viewDidAppear`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this easily with `NSNotificationCenter`:

1st View Controller:

```
// Assuming your label is set up in IB, otherwise initialize in viewDidLoad
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UILabel *label;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Add an observer so we can receive notifications from our other view controller
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]addObserver:self selector:@selector(updateLabel:) name:@"UpdateLabel" object:nil];
}

- (void)updateLabel:(NSNotification*)notification
{
    // Update the UILabel's text to that of the notification object posted from the other view controller
    self.label.text = notification.object;
}

- (void)dealloc
{ 
    // Clean up; make sure to add this
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]removeObserver:self];
}
```

2nd View Controller:

```
- (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidDisappear:animated];

    NSString *updateLabelString = @"Your Text Here";        
    // Posting the notification back to our sending view controller with the updateLabelString being the posted object
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]postNotificationName:@"UpdateLabel" object:updateLabelString;
}
```

Comment: implemented successfully . simple way of passing values when popping out the view controller .

Answer (score 2):

You can use delegate for passing objects to parent view controller while use of `PopViewController`

for step by step use of delegate [click here](http://jameslin.herokuapp.com/blog/2013/10/15/hello-world/) for demo.

and this question is for your help [Question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11885673/how-to-pass-data-back-from-one-view-to-other-view-in-ios)