# How to pass data back from a view to a view in a tab bar controller with a done button

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller

I have a tab bar controller with 4 tabs. From my 3 tab i have a button that takes you to another view with a date picker in it. I would like to return this date to my 3 tab through a done button but unfortunately the data does not go back. I have found this article [How to pass data back from one view to other View in IOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11885673/how-to-pass-data-back-from-one-view-to-other-view-in-ios)

which I am able to go back but the data does not transfer. Here is my code:

```
NSDateFormatter *Format = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[Format setDateFormat:@"MMM dd, yyyy"];
NSString *Date = [Format stringFromDate:selectDate.date];
NSLog(Date);
BookArtistViewController *parentView = (BookArtistViewController *)[self.tabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:2];
parentView.Date = Date;
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you use the AppDelegate? You can create a date property in your AppDelegate and then assign the UiDatePicker date to it.

In your AppDelegate.h create the property:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSDate *myDate;
```

In the view controller that contains your UIDatePicker import the AppDelegate.h then in your "done" button save the chosen date into myDate:

```
#import "myViewController.h"
#import "AppDelegate.h"

@interface myViewController ()
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIDatePicker *myUIDatePicker;
- (IBAction)saveDate:(id)sender;
@end

- (IBAction)saveDate:(id)sender {
    AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    appDelegate.myDate = self.myUIDatePicker.date;
    NSLog(@"%@", appDelegate.myDate );
}
```

Now, in your 3rd TAB, import the AppDelegate.h, create a label named dateLabel and create its property:

```
#import "myThirdTabViewController.h"
#import "AppDelegate.h"

@interface myThirdTabViewController ()
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *dateLabel;
@end
```

and put this code in the viewWillAppear:

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    dateFormatter.dateStyle = NSDateFormatterMediumStyle;
    dateFormatter.timeStyle = NSDateFormatterShortStyle;
    self.dateLabel.text = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:appDelegate.myDate];
}
```

The chosen date will appear in the label.

Comment: Another option would be to create a singleton to hold onto the data. I try to avoid adding anything to my app delegate that doesn't have to do with the lifecycle of my app.

Comment: Thank you for this ideas! @Diego I was wondering, I tried using this code but it gives me an error what would I need to import to make it work? I tried app delegate.h but no luck

Comment: @AdamPro how would I create a singleton to share with both views?? Thank you again!

Comment: Thank you @AdamPro13 I'm going to check this out!

Comment: Awesome the app delegate solution worked! I changed the smappdelegate to app delegate. What is the main difference between them two? @diego

Comment: Ye, i'm sorry for that, it was late and i was copy pasting from my code cause i'm lazy XDD. I corrected the answer. It's more clear now. Glad you got it right anyway. Peace.